# PHP array access

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP 5 with mySQL:

`$line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);`

When I do this, I can see the results of the query printed:

```
foreach ($line as $data)
    {
        echo ($data . ", ");
    }
```

But if I do this instead:

`echo ($line[0] . " " . $line[1] . " " . $line[2]);`

I don't see anything. Also I can't assign a value from $line:

`$values[] = $line[0];` // fails - doesn't assign anything

Why? And what should I be doing instead?

Comment: While you're developing, turn on all errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. You would then see some `E_NOTICE` level errors about undefined array indexes

Comment: the result from the mysql query are not 0-indexed array , instead the keys are the culomn names of the DB tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've nominated to retrieve records as associative entries only (`MYSQL_ASSOC`). This means your `$line` array will not contain numeric indices.

If you only want numeric arrays, use [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php).

Associative only, [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

You can also retrieve a mixed numeric and associative array using `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)` however this will give you duplicate entries in your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You told MySQL that you want to fetch the row as an array, which means $line is not a 0-index array, it's an associative array, which means the keys of the array are the column names of the table(s) you selected from.

```
var_dump($line); // Will display the keys
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo ($line["id"] . " " . $line["id"] . " " . $line["id"]);
```

so instead of using a index number like [0] you use the corresponding column-name

Comment: That would only be possible using [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) or by casting the associative array to `(object)`